# How to do DI in asp.net core middleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I am trying to inject dependency into my middleware constructor as follows

```
public class CreateCompanyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public CreateCompanyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next
        , UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager
        )
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

My Startup.cs file looks like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    ...

    app.UseMiddleware<CreateCompanyMiddleware>();

    ...
```

But I am getting this error

> An error occurred while starting the application.
>   InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Common.Models.ApplicationUser]' from root provider.
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type serviceType, IServiceScope scope, IServiceScope rootScope)

Answer (score 226, accepted):

`UserManager<ApplicationUser>` is (by default) registered as a *scoped* dependency, whereas your `CreateCompanyMiddleware` middleware is constructed at app startup (effectively making it a *singleton*). This is a fairly standard error saying that you can't take a *scoped* dependency into a *singleton* class.

The fix is simple in this case - you can inject the `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` into your `Invoke` method:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    await _next.Invoke(context);
}
```

This is documented in [ASP.NET Core Middleware: Per-request middleware dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-2.2#per-request-middleware-dependencies):

> Because middleware is constructed at app startup, not per-request, *scoped* lifetime services used by middleware constructors aren't shared with other dependency-injected types during each request. If you must share a *scoped* service between your middleware and other types, add these services to the `Invoke` method's signature. The `Invoke` method can accept additional parameters that are populated by DI:

Comment: Nice simple solution that worked for me. Note, if you forget to add the DI classes in the startup.cs then errors in the middleware won't always appear on screen and break points won't get hit. It can appear that the code is working, but it's probably not.

Answer (score 32):

Another way to do that is to create a middleware by `IMiddleware` interface and register it as a service

For example , the middleware

```
public class CreateCompanyMiddlewareByInterface : IMiddleware
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public CreateCompanyMiddlewareByInterface(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager )
    {
        this._userManager = userManager;
    }


    public Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        return next(context);
    }
}
```

and service registeration :

```
services.AddScoped<CreateCompanyMiddlewareByInterface>();
```

3. So why it happens ?

The middlewares using `IMiddleware` are built by `UseMiddlewareInterface(appBuilder, middlewareType type)`  :

```
private static IApplicationBuilder UseMiddlewareInterface(IApplicationBuilder app, Type middlewareType)
{
    return app.Use(next =>
    {
        return async context =>
        {
            var middlewareFactory = (IMiddlewareFactory)context.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IMiddlewareFactory));
            if (middlewareFactory == null) { /* throw ... */ }

            var middleware = middlewareFactory.Create(middlewareType);
            if (middleware == null) { /* throw ... */ }

            try{
                await middleware.InvokeAsync(context, next);
            }
            finally{
                middlewareFactory.Release(middleware);
            }
        };
    });
}
```

here the codes inside the `context=>{}` are executed per-request . So every time there's an incoming request , the `var middleware = middlewareFactory.Create(middlewareType);` will be executed and then ask for a middleware of `middlewareType` ( which is already registered as a service ) from the `ServiceProvider` .

As for by-convention middlewares , there's no factory creating them .

Those instances are all created by `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance()` at startup time . And any `Invoke` method of by-convention middlewares , such as

```
Task Invoke(HttpContext context,UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManage, ILoggerFactory loggeryFactory , ... )
```

will be compiled into a function like below :

```
Task Invoke(Middleware instance, HttpContext httpContext, IServiceprovider provider)
{
    var useManager  /* = get service from service provider */ ;
    var log = /* = get service from service provider */ ;
    // ... 
    return instance.Invoke(httpContext,userManager,log, ...);
}
```

As you see , here the instance is created at startup time , and those services of `Invoke` method are requested per request .

Comment: The Factory approach is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/extensibility