# How can I modify a middleware or its registration to correctly use a scoped service?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, middleware

I'm developing a multi-tenant application in .NET and I've run into an issue where I need to access a scoped service, ITenantProvider, from within a custom middleware, TenantMiddleware. However, when I try to run my application, I receive the following error:

> Cannot resolve scoped service 'MyNameSpace.ITenantProvider' from root
> provider.

Here is the middleware:

```
public class TenantMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ITenantProvider _tenantProvider;

    public TenantMiddleware(ITenantProvider tenantProvider, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _tenantProvider = tenantProvider;
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Logic to set tenant ID
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

Startup config:

```
services.AddScoped<ITenantProvider, TenantProviderImplementation>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IDBService, DBService>();
app.UseMiddleware<TenantMiddleware>();
```

The goal of the tenant ITenantProvider is to be set with a tenant Id (as a scoped) and the to be consumed by other services while it is injected as scoped to a transient db services.

```
public interface ITenantProvider
{
    public Guid GetTenantId();
    public void SetTenantId(Guid tenantId);
}
```

The DBService has the tenantId provider as a dependancy:

```
DbService(ITenantProvider tenant) { ... }
```

The most imprtant thing that the method DbLogic will be able to get from the injected `ITenantProvider` the tenantId via the method `GetTenantId()` that is correspondent with the one-time-called method (via the middleware) of `SetTenantId(Guid tenantId)`

```
DbLogic()
{
    Guid tenantId = _tenantProvider.GetTenantId();
}
```

I understand that the issue is related to trying to inject a scoped service (`ITenantProvider`) into a middleware that is a singleton, but I'm not sure how to correctly structure this to avoid the error.

Comment: If your middleware does not implement the `IMiddleware` interface then you can inject scoped object to the `Invoke` method.

Comment: If you do implement the `IMiddleware` interface then you can inject scoped object via ctor. For further information check this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52204022/how-to-do-di-in-asp-net-core-middleware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resolve it from the context in the `Invoke` call (remove the ctor parameter):

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var tenantProvider = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITenantProvider>();
    // Logic to set tenant ID
    await _next(context);
}
```

Or inject it directly to the method parameters:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ITenantProvider provider)
{
    // Logic to set tenant ID
    await _next(context);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, see the updated question, I wonder if getting it via the context as scoped tenantProvider and set the tenantId, then what would happened if transient db service will ask tenantProvider for its tenantId ?

Comment: The HttpContext generally runs with a scope that lives as long as HttpContext (or HTTP request/response pipeline). So a scoped service instance that you resolve from the scope of the HttpContext should be the same instance that you get via DI anywhere else from the same scope, e.g. in a controller.
So when you resolve the ITenantProvider in the middleware and set the tenantId to a field in the class you should get the same instance of ITenantProvider with the same tenantId in the controller, or in another service that you resolve within the dependency tree resolved for the controller.

Comment: @ShaharShokrani what fectus wrote. Transient services constructed by scope are part of the scope. P.S. can't definitely tell without having full code overview but in general I would recommend against registering db services as transient.